# DOMDocument::loadHTML error

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I build a script that combines all css on a page together to use it in my cms. It worked fine for a long time now i i get this error:

> **Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 10 in
>   **css.php** on line **26**
>  
>  **Warning**: 
>   DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag nav invalid in
>   Entity, line: 10 in **css.php** on line **26**
>  
>   **Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag
>   section invalid in Entity, line: 22 in **css.php** on line
>   **26**
>  This is the php script

This is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
include ('../global.php');

if ($usetpl == '1') {
    $client = New client();
    $tplname = $client->template();
    $location = "../templates/$tplname/header.php";
    $page = file_get_contents($location);
} else {
    $page = file_get_contents('../index.php');
}

class StyleSheets extends DOMDocument implements IteratorAggregate
{

    public function __construct ($source)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->loadHTML($source);
    }

    public function getIterator ()
    {
        static $array;
        if (NULL === $array) {
            $xp = new DOMXPath($this);
            $expression = '//head/link[@rel="stylesheet"]/@href';
            $array = array();
            foreach ($xp->query($expression) as $node)
                $array[] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
        return new ArrayIterator($array);
    }
}

foreach (new StyleSheets($page) as $index => $file) {
    $css = file_get_contents($file);
    echo $css;
}
```

Comment: This issue had been reported for PHP at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60021 which in turn spawned a feature request in the underlying libxml2: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761534

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Header, Nav and Section are elements from HTML5. Because HTML5 developers felt it is too difficult to remember Public and System Identifiers, the DocType declaration is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In other words, there is no DTD to check, which will make DOM use the HTML4 Transitional DTD and that doesnt contain those elements, hence the Warnings.

To surpress the Warnings, put

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

before the call to `loadHTML` and

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

after it.

An alternative would be to use https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-php.

Comment: did that, now i get a blank page

Comment: @user1079160 that is another problem ! Gordon has the good answer, thanks !

Comment: @Gordan how do you fix the blank page issue?

Comment: I had the same blank-page issue.  My mistake was using `print $document->saveXML()` instead of `$document->saveHTML()`.  The HTML version doesn't make certain formatting conversions that the XML version does.  If that's not the issue, try checking the source of the output to see what tags, if any, are present.  It should clue you in to what's happening under the hood.  Also, don't forget `var_dump`!

Answer (score 26):

With a DOMDocument object, you should be able to place an @ before the load method in order to SUPPRESS all WARNINGS.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
```

And carry on.

Comment: This is a terrible solution as you will make errors on this line a nightmare to debug.  @Gordon's solution is much better.

Comment: its working man

Answer (score 15):

HTML5 elements are still not supported, but you can silence libxml errors completely with the `$options` parameter.

Just set

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("html5.html", LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

This option is preferred over `@` which silences PHP errors.

But be careful, libxml is very forgiving and it will parse a broken HTML document. **If you silence libxml errors you might not even be aware that the HTML is malformed.**

Comment: Are there any options to silence only errors, which were thrown because of HTML 5 elements?

Comment: @jnbm Not to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Most people do *not* realize the difference between HTML and XML as languages and HTML and XML in regards to *parsers*. A parser takes code and the HTML and XML parsers are completely different. While there are some minor things XML parsers will tolerate in browsers (e.g. duplicate `id` values) they don't mess around with junk that *looks* like code.

PHP's XML parser is even stricter and doesn't allow duplicate `id` values. Additionally since anything can be an element (e.g. `footer`, `header`, `section`) PHP's XML parser will *not* complain about unknown HTML5+ elements.

```
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

For anyone developing on client side I highly recommend using the XML parser to handle your HTML5 code and since I started developing in the 2000s in to 2020 Gecko browsers (e.g. Waterfox, Firefox) have the best XML parser as the entire page will break and you'll get an *explicit* error message. Stricter code yields better results if you can comprehend quality eventually yields quantity though the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DOMDocument you might want to use this comfortable DomCralwer component from the Symfony:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

```
composer require symfony/dom-crawler
```

Then you can do cool stuff like

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler->filter(".whatever .wild > .query  ~.you[name=it]")->each(function($node, $i){
    print_r($node->text());

    //or something like this
    $node->children()->each(function($node_inner, $j){
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```