# PHP Scrape; save as variables for MySQL Insert

Tags: php, html, mysql, scrape

I'm successfully scraping a website to get space separated data off of the page:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somewebsite.com");
$scores_doc = new DOMDocument();

$scores_doc->loadHTML($html);
$scores_path = new DOMXPath($scores_doc);
$scores_row  = $scores_xpath->query('//td[@class="first"]');

foreach($scores_row as $row){
    echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
```

Example output:

```
23 Crimmons, Bob (CA)
48 Silas, Greg (RI)
82 Huston, Roger (TX)
21 Lester, Terry (NC)
```

Instead of printing the output using 'echo' I need to split the value into four smaller pieces and into variables (array or otherwise). I know the MySQL side very well, I just don't use PHP day to day. I tried (in place of the 'echo' and after defining it as an array):

```
$data[] = echo $row->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Remove the `echo` in `$data[] = echo $row->nodeValue;`.

Comment: Follow up: when is a 'space' not a space (and I have utf-8 defined)? The info all goes into data[0] - even if I perform a 'explode'.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Found the need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149180/domdocumentloadhtml-error) to suppress the warnings by `loadHTML`.

Answer (score 4):

> **A sidenote on the used syntax**:
>   If you just want to assign the whole `23 Crimmons, Bob (CA)` string as one string to an array. You should use the right syntax.
>
> ```
> $data[] = echo $row->nodeValue;
> ```
>
> Should be:
>
> ```
> $data[] = $row->nodeValue;
> ```

---

### Three possible solutions to your problem.

### Solution 1: Improve scraping

The best way to scrape those four values seperately would be to query more specifically. You can try to update your xpath query on line:

```
$scores_xpath->query('//td[@class="first"]');
```

The query you can use depends on the structure of the page you're scraping.

### Solution 2: Splitting string using PHP explode

You could use PHP's [explode function](https://php.net/explode) to separate the string, *but note that will give some problems when there are spaces used in a name.*

```
echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

Can be something like:

```
// Assuming that $row->nodeValue will have the string `23 Crimmons, Bob (CA)` as it's value 
$explodeRow = explode(' ', $row->nodeValue);

/*
* $explodeRow now contains four values. 
*
* $explodeRow[0] = "23";
* $explodeRow[1] = "Crimmons,";
* $explodeRow[2] = "Bob";
* $explodeRow[3] = "(CA)";
*/
```

*You can choose to remove the `(` and `)` characters in `$explodeRow[3]` with the PHP [str_replace](https://php.net/str_replace), [preg_replace](https://php.net/preg_replace) or [substr](https://php.net/substr) function for example.*

### Solution 3: Splitting string using regular expressions

Alternatively you can decide to fetch the first two numbers first. Then to fetch the last part between `()`. Then seperate the two remaining values by `,`. *But this can also generates problems when multiple commas are used.*

Example of this solution will be, something like:

```
preg_match("~^(\d+)~", $row->nodeValue, $number);
$number[1]; # will be 23

preg_match("#\((.*?)\)#", $row->nodeValue, $last);
$last[1]; # will be CA

$middleExp = explode("(", $row->nodeValue, 2);
$middle = substr((strlen($number[1])-1), strlen($row->nodeValue), $middleExp[0]);

$middleExp2 = explode(",", $middle);
$middleL = $middleExp2[0]; # will be Crimmons
$middleR = $middleExp2[1]; # will be Bob
```

Comment: Thanks for the consolidation of 'explode' into one command. The only reason your other break up option won't work - the score could be 1, 2 or 3 digits.  Is there anything to change the appearance of a space in the output? On the screen it sure looks like a space between the values - but 'explode' isn't working and everything is still piling into [0].

Comment: Right now I can't tell what is between the values - looks like a single space but since explode isn't working with a single space, I'm trying other non-printable characters - white spaces, tabs, etc. The preg_match to get the $number did not work...

Comment: Try to return the ASCII value of that "space"-looking character. You can use `substr()` to get to the right position of the string and `ord()` to check the ASCII value. Then lookup the corresponding ASCII code, for example here http://ascii.cl/. And try to explode using that character or replace it first.

Comment: Took another look at the HTML - &nbsp - explode doesn't appear to work with it so I'll try to work the Splitting option. Unless someone has a way to explode with &nbsp...

Comment: Try to do something like str_replace(chr(160), " ", $row->nodeValue); or str_replace("\xA0", " ", $row->nodeValue)(i didn't test it). But chr(160) will be a non-braking space. Or instead of replacing, exploding using \xA0 or chr(160).

Comment: Thanks again - will try after lunch. PS - looked at your $middle = ... statement - I think $middleExp[0] should be the 1st var for substr. I also re-did the number preg_match (and will update). So I'm getting the score and state.  Just need the last and first names.

Comment: str_replace("\xA0","/", $row->nodeValue); did allow me to get slashes in that I could then use to extract the first name. But there's still something invisible between the score and the last name. And get this: I found the strcspn function and ran it to find the first Capital letter - for a line '62 Smith...' (something between the 62 and S) - it returned 33! - something very strange. Thanks to everyone - I think I'm close enough to call this question resolved.

Comment: @user3741598 can you mark this question as answered if it helped you out?