# PHP - preg_match unable to get all elements from html url

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to get the innertext of html tag  from a url (defimedia.info) but i get only 1 output. The code i tried is:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.defimedia.info");
preg_match("'<h3>(.*?)<h3>'si", $html, $match);
echo($match[1]);
```

even when i try to use foreach or i try to use $match[2], it does not work. Any help would certainly be appreciated.
regards
bhaamb

Comment: Maybe using a html parser would be good idea. Your regex will not match h3 if it has a class `<h3 class="large">`

Comment: @MartinGottweis Sir it doesnt have a class

Comment: I would use an HTML parser (Like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) when parsing HTML instead of using regex, much simpler and easier t use imho. It does all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need preg_match_all function. Documented here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

try like this.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.defimedia.info");
preg_match_all('/<h3>(.*?)<h3>/si', $html, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex is not the correct tool for parsing HTML/XML instead you can use DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You can use `DOMDocument` like as

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.defimedia.info");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$h3s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach ($h3s as $h3) {
    echo $h3->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

[Why did I used `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149180/domdocumentloadhtml-error)