# Need help getting string from a file in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a txt file that is filled with html code in it. I'm trying to create a PHP page that searches the code and gets the "username" for me:

Here is a small sample of the page:

```
  <div class="search-result-details">
    <div class="employee-name">This is my name!</div>
    <ul class="employee-details">
      <li><span class="label">Login</span>username</li>
      <li><span class="label">Employee ID</span>####</li>
      <li><span class="label">Barcode ID</span>###</li>
      <li><span class="label">Status</span>Active</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="org-details">
      <li><span class="label">Location</span>SAT1 (755)</li>
      <li><span class="label">Shift</span>AAAA</li>
      <li><span class="label">Department</span>1231</li>
      <li><span class="label">Area</span>26</li>
      <li><span class="label">Crew</span>0</li>
      <li><span class="label">Supervisor</span>manager name</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
```

and I need to grab the username from the following line:

```
<li><span class="label">Login</span>username</li>
```

I have this already that at least grabs the line I need:

```
    <?php
$file = 'log.txt';
$searchfor = '<ul class="employee-details">
      <li><span class="label">Login</span>';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}

?>
```

Current Output:

```
<ul class="employee-details">
  <li><span class="label">Login</span>username</li>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i prefer to parsing HTML files with *DOMDocument* and *DOMXpath* maybe it will be yours too

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit hacky, this is one way you could do it.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

preg_match("/(Login<\/span>)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(<\/li>)/", $contents, $matches);

if (is_array($matches) && isset($matches[2])) {
   $username = trim($matches[2]);
}
```

Of course, that middle capture group would need to support whatever characters are possible in usernames.

Also be aware that this will *break* if that HTML structure is changed ever.

And finally, if there can be more than one username in a file, you can use `preg_match_all` and then `$matches[2]` will be an array of usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML('<div class="search-result-details">
    <div class="employee-name">This is my name!</div>
    <ul class="employee-details">
      <li><span class="label">Login</span>username</li>
      <li><span class="label">Employee ID</span>####</li>
      <li><span class="label">Barcode ID</span>###</li>
      <li><span class="label">Status</span>Active</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="org-details">
      <li><span class="label">Location</span>SAT1 (755)</li>
      <li><span class="label">Shift</span>AAAA</li>
      <li><span class="label">Department</span>1231</li>
      <li><span class="label">Area</span>26</li>
      <li><span class="label">Crew</span>0</li>
      <li><span class="label">Supervisor</span>manager name</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$html = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = '';
foreach ($html->query("//*[@class='label']") as $value) {
    if ($value->textContent == 'Login') {
        $result = $value->nextSibling->textContent;
        break;
    }
}

echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
username
```

The reason for [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) is to suppress validation errors as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149180/domdocumentloadhtml-error).

Comment: @dkeeper09 the same way you are currently, with `file_get_contents`