# How to get HTML from file_get_content PHP then unminify it

Tags: php, domdocument, file-get-contents, codeigniter-4

I want to get the HTML content in this page using **file_get_contents** as string :

https://www.emitennews.com/search/

Then I want to unminify the html code.

So far what I done to unminify it :

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.emitennews.com/search/");                                        
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
print $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

But in the code above I got is error :

> DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 1

What is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149180/domdocumentloadhtml-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code :

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.emitennews.com/search/");                                        
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
print $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

The problem is the site using HTML5. So we need to put :

**libxml_use_internal_errors(true);**

Answer (score 0):

You must add the xml tag at the first line:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
```

Comment: I add the xml tag. But not working. When I view the source page, the html still minify.

Comment: You can prepare a simple $html value likes "<html><body>abc</body></html>" for testing first. I guess the html you got from the website has invalid XML structure.

Comment: Thank You for response. The problem is in the HTML5 that website use. I need to put "libxml_use_internal_errors(true);" before load the html.